# How exactly does the onClick binding work in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React JS for the first time as it is the likely approach my team will be taking at work on a new project. I am trying to understand this onClick binding behavior and what exactly it is doing.

I looked at some articles that try to explain binding specific instances of components/objects to their respective functions and they sort of make sense. But using 'this.props.onClick(i)' doesn't make much sense to me.

So does that code pass squares[i] as the props and somehow onClick within the Square component this updates the value of the button? When running the program that is what it seems to do but I just can't seem to wrap my head around this logic. Especially since I am coming from a back-end background with C# and Java. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Update:
The whole app. To give more context...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      history: [{
        squares: Array(9).fill(null)
      }],
      xIsNext: true,
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      history: history.concat([{
        squares: squares
      }]),
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

    let status;
    if (winner) {
      status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
    } else {
      status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    }

    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board
            squares={current.squares}
            onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{status}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] == squares[b] && squares[a] == squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste all the code this doesn't look quite right

Comment: Yep. Give me one moment.

Comment: The entire app's code has been added to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole idea in react is to lift your state up.
In this code,

Game is the parent of all and it will define what happens when I click on child Square.  Instead of Square dealing with it itself,  Game keeps handling of onClick to itself and passes down to board as a prop like this.

```
<Board squares={current.squares} onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)} />
```

Now Board in turn passes the prop onClick it received when called from Game to it's child Square like this as a prop.

```
<Square value={this.props.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)} />
```

So Game's handleClick is assigned to onClick prop of Board which is assigned to onClick prop of Square.  Thus Square tells Board that I was clicked but I don't know what to do with it.  So I will transfer responsibility to you and you can call whatever you passed me as a prop when you called me (Square).  Board does the same thing and passes responsibility to Game which actually knows that onClick I should call handleClick event that I have within me.

```
handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      history: history.concat([{
        squares: squares
      }]),
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
    });
  }
```

`handleClick in Game passed to Board as onClick prop ->  onClick prop of Board passed to Square as onClick prop`

Thus, clicking on Square becomes reverse operation then
`Square says my onClick prop is actually passed by Board -> Board says my onClick prop is actually passed by Game -> Game says I know how to handleClick`

[image: Graphical Representation of above scenario]

Comment: That's a very interesting explaination. So it is way to pass down the handleClick function onto the children components, and eventually the call moves up the stack back to the Game component which is the parent to complete the event.

Comment: Exactly.  Added more explanation to the comment.  Hope that helps.  Do mark it as answered once all your queries are taken care of.  Cheers

Comment: I will do so. Thanks!

Comment: Added graphical representation just in case text is too verbose for some users.

Comment: @noor What about parameter i passed as to Board refer to 
 onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)
There is no i in Game

Comment: @somegeek the parameter to click events is the actual event object.  so in this i represents the event object.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing would be to understand the structure of this app. From parent to child component. The Game class component is the most Parent component then the Board Class component then the Square functional component.

the "props" pattern is essentially a way to pass down properties from parent components to child components.

So the Game component is passing down 2 props to the child board component

```
  <Board
    squares={current.squares}
    onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
  />
```

This allows the Board component to access these properties with the syntax "this.props" then the name of the property. Then the Board component is taking these props and further passing it down to its own child component RenderSquare. So this allows the deeply nested child component to access the onClick event of the parent most Game component.

This is not recommended practice tho since props are supposed to be read only. IF you would like to have a child component update and change state in a parent component, then you will need to use Context.